# Кнопка - переключатель

Tags: jquery, ajax

Подскажите как сделать следующее на jQuery: есть красная кнопка (Выключить), как сделать так: если на кнопку нажали, то кнопка принимает другой стиль (зеленая) и текст - Включить. Пробовал сделать сделать подобное из исходников, но не получалось, всегда были какие-то ляпы и не работало...

Comment: [jQuery - write *less* do **more**](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Wz8Z8/1/)

Comment: [простой способ переключать список классов](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Wz8Z8/2/)

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как-то так http://jsfiddle.net/Wz8Z8/

**HTML:**

```
<button class='red' id='js-button'>Нажать</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red {
    color: red;
}

.green {
    color: green
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#js-button').on('click', function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('red')) {
        $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('green').html('Ещё раз');
        return
    }
    $(this).removeClass('green').addClass('red').html('Нажать');
});
```

Comment: спасибо, что надо :)